# UML Deployment with several datacenters

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

How does one depict datacenters in a deployment scenario where infrastructure is distributed geographically in UML notation?

Comment: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/web-application-clusters-uml-deployment-diagram-example.html?context=depl-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple boundaries standing for locations which you use to surround certain components/nodes. Also you can use packages and individual diagrams which you can include as frame in a main diagram:

[image]

Comment: I found the new picture on the next side of my book. I should have read it more thoroughly ;-).